# async await in Protractor is ignored

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm new to testing and JS in general. I'm trying to write my first async await test but I cannot make it work.

I have set `protractor.promise.USE_PROMISE_MANAGER = false`; to be able to use `async await`.

When I set the selenium promise manager to false, I receive as expected the error `TypeError: Unable to create a managed promise instance: the promise manager has been disabled by the SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER environment variable: undefined.`

However, when I add async await to all the abstraction layers in the code, the same error is persisting. How can I make the following test work with `async await`?

**login.spec.js**

```
protractor.promise.USE_PROMISE_MANAGER = false;

describe('Login page :', () => {
  const loginPage = new objects.Login(),
        el = new objects.Element(),
        ec = new objects.ExpectedCondition()


  beforeAll( async () => {
    await loginPage.go();
  });

  describe('with invalid credentials', () => {

    beforeEach( async () => {
      await browser.refresh();
    }); 

    it('should fail to log in without credentials', async () => {
      await loginPage.submit();

      await expect(ec.isVisible(loginPage.selectors.login.errors.lblEmailValidation));
      await expect(ec.isVisible(loginPage.selectors.login.errors.lblPasswordValidation));
    });
```

**login.po.js**

```
class Login {
  ...
  async submit() {
    await this.element.clickElement(this.selectors.login.button.btnSubmit)
  }
  ...
}
```

**element.js**

```
class Element {
...
  async clickElement(selector) {
    return await this.getElement(selector).click();
  }
...
}
```

**expectedCondition.js**

```
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

class ExpectedCondition {
  constructor() {
   this.el = new objects.Element();
  }

 async isVisible(selector) {
    return await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(this.el.getElement(selector)));
  }
}
```

**element.js**

```
class Element {
  getElement(selector) {
    return element(by.css(selector));
  }
  ...
}
```

**The error I get:**

```
Failures:
1) Login page : with invalid credentials should fail to log in without credentials
  Message:
    TypeError: Unable to create a managed promise instance: the promise manager has been disabled by the SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER environment variable: undefined
  Stack:
    TypeError: Unable to create a managed promise instance: the promise manager has been disabled by the SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER environment variable: undefined
        at new ManagedPromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1030:13)
        at new Deferred (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1454:20)
        at new Task (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2778:5)
        at ControlFlow.execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2477:16)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:94:19)
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/async-await.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You should remove your `protractor.promise.USE_PROMISE_MANAGER = false;` from `login.spec.js` and from all places in `*.spec.js` files;

2) You should update your `protractor.conf` file:

```
config = {
...
SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
}
```

Comment: This setting doesn't seem to update from one set of tests to another. We have 2 sets of tests in different paths, each w/ separate protractor.conf files - one set to false. All settings get picked up except this PROMISE_MANAGER. We reverse the order, and the 1st setting rules the 2nd test set.

Comment: feel free to create a new question on SO and/or issue in Protractor repo